# What is the purpose of dependency maven-model?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I came across this dependency in one project pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-model</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.9</version>
</dependency>
```

There is not much of detail on the [page](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.1/maven-model/) of maven-model project, but looks like it is just a definition (XSD) of pom schema and maven can obtain it without explicit declaration (as all other projects I've seen do not declare this dependency).

What could be the purpose of adding it explicitly?

Comment: Some people do not like to use transitive dependencies and want to declare them manually, instead.

Comment: A usual java project shouldn't define it as a dependency if it does is highly likely wrong. Usually only maven-plugin projects sometimes add this model. It's not the XSD. It contains the code to read the Maven model (in other words the `pom.xml`) and provides several generated classes which represent the model as `POM` implies `Project Object Model`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a dependency which provides a Pojo model for maven files. You probably need it when you're writing a maven extension / plugin. I don't think it is useful for a "normal" project which happens to *use* maven.